# how to pass form_builder in jquery escape_javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, actionview, actionviewhelper

I have two classes `Message` and `Comment` which is associated as follows

```
class Message ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comments_attributes
  has_many :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end

class Comment ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :message
end
```

I modeled my form as

```
= form_for @message do |f|
  f.text_field :msg
  %a#add-comment Add Comment

_comment.html.haml
  = f.fields_for :comments do |c|
      c.text_field :value
```

When 'Add comment' button is clicked I am appending the comment input to the form f, through jquery as follows

```
$('#add-comment').click(function() {
  $('#add-comment').prepend(("#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => "comment", f: f))}");  
});
```

But I can't able to access this form, I am getting

```
Undefined local variable or method 'f'
```

How to do this?

Comment: where are keeping your javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your form.  I assume:

```
  = f.fields_for :comments do |c|
      c.text_field :value
```

Is in your comment partial.

So your form should be like this and passing the f variable to the partial

```
= form_for @message do |f|
  f.text_field :msg
  %a#add-comment Add Comment

  = render :partial => 'comment', :locals => {:f => f}
```